# Design RESTFul GET with URL as resource

Tags: rest, web-services, url, flask, api-design

What would be the best approach to implement a GET REST API in order to check if a given URL existed in the database.

Each GET request will have the following parts : hostname, port, origin, path, and query.

My idea is to setup the resource as follows.

```
/urlservice/1/{hostname}/{port}/{origin}/{path}/{query}
```

But this seems very verbose since it will results in resource urls like:

```
/urlservice/1/google.com/80/"https://google.com/"/"/search"/"?q=aba"
```

What is a better way of designing this?

Comment: Just pass the URL as a query parameter. Make sure to url encode it

Answer (score 0):

The main caveat with REST when designing your URI structure is that you follow the URI spec. That being said, looking at the URI spec in regards to the structure it has a couple important notes to help with your question:

[1.2.3.  Hierarchical Identifiers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-1.2.3)

> The URI syntax is organized hierarchically, with components listed in
> order of decreasing significance from left to right.  For some URI
> schemes, the visible hierarchy is limited to the scheme itself:
> everything after the scheme component delimiter (":") is considered
> opaque to URI processing.  Other URI schemes make the hierarchy
> explicit and visible to generic parsing algorithms.
>
> The generic syntax uses the slash ("/"), question mark ("?"), and
> number sign ("#") characters to delimit components that are
> significant to the generic parser's hierarchical interpretation of an
> identifier...

Now in regards to the query string:

[3.4.  Query](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4)

> The query component contains non-hierarchical data that, along with
> data in the path component (Section 3.3), serves to identify a
> resource within the scope of the URI's scheme and naming authority
> (if any).  The query component is indicated by the first question
> mark ("?") character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character
> or by the end of the URI...

With the above, looking at your URI you need to determine whether your structure is hierarchical or not to follow the URI spec to satisfy REST. Of course, there is a bit of subjectivity here but looking at what you have, most (if not all) of the parameters you called out look like candidates for use in a query string is as it is non-hierarchical. To that end, I'd recommend moving them to the query string.

```
/urlservice/1?hostname={hostname}&port={port}&origin={origin}&path={path}&query={query}
```

Again, as there is some subjectivity and you know your domain better than others, use the above guidance and make your best judgement call.

Answer (score 0):

You could decompose it to be service based rather than specifying everything in the request:

```
/urlservice/1/{service}/{request}
```

The services would be 'service based' so a google search service would know how to build a google search url:

```
/urlservice/1/google/aba
```

would be resolved to:

```
https://google.com/search/?q=aba
```

by the google service. It also means all clients wouldn't have to change if google changed their service parameters. Only the google service would change its internal implementation of the url builder.